# Join 2 dataframes with column of dateTime in df.x filtered on dateStart dateEnd in df.y?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset with start and end times for events (called df_time), and another dataset with when an event happened (df_val). I want to do an inner join the two dataframes on whether df_val took place within the 2 columns of df_time.

```
start = c(1, 5, 7, 4)
end = c(2, 7, 11, 7)
event_id = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
df_time = data.frame(start, end, event_id)

time = c(3, 6, 2, 10, 11)
val = c(100, 20, 30, 40, 50)
df_val = data.frame(time, val)
```

I am aware of map2_dfr, and am using it as such:

```
library(tidyverse)

unique(  map2_dfr(  df_time$start, df_time$end,
                    ~filter(df_val, time >= .x, time <= .y)  )  )
```

However, this gives me back only columns in df_val; is there any way to get back the columns from df_time for an output like:

```
  time val  start end event_id
1    2  30  1     2   'a'
2    6  20  5     7   'b'
3   10  40  7     11  'c'
4   6   50  4     7   'd'
```

Edit: setDT is very close to the correct answer!  However, df_time has na values for val and time for rows that had no corresponding values in df_val instead of being omitted altogether. For example, considering the below to be Case 2:

```
Case 2

time=c(3,6,10,11)
val=c(100,20,40,50)
df_val=data.frame(time,val)

start = c(1, 5, 7, 4)
end = c(2, 7, 11, 7)
event_id = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
df_time = data.frame(start, end, event_id)

setDT(df_time)[df_val, c("val", "time")  := .(val, time) , 
         on = .(start <= time,  end >= time)]

df_time
```

Output:

```
df_time
start   end   event_id   val   time
1       2     a          NA    NA
5       7     b          20    6
7       11    c          50    11
4       7     d          20    6
```

expected/correct output:

```
start   end   event_id   val   time
5       7     b          20    6
7       11    c          50    11
4       7     d          20    6
```

Comment: They were wrong, I have just updated it, thank you!

Comment: For the case2, what is the expected

Comment: For case 2- If start and ends within df_time do not have a resulting set of data within df_val- that row within df_time will not be returned. Currently- event_id 'a' is being returned despite having no values in df_val (cells corresponding to val and time are NA). I can update the answer with a table in a few minutes.

Comment: Can you update with the expected output as well for cross reference

Comment: Just updated my post with the expected output.

Comment: I understand what you meant.  My thoughts were that you want to return 'df_time' with all the columns, and that is the reason I used `:=`, but you can wrap with `na.omit` to remove the `NA` rows

Comment: Can you check my update.   Issue is that I am creating a column in the original dataset with `:=`.  So, naturally, if there is no matching row, it would be by default `NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is a non-equi join in `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df_time)`), join with 'df_val' `on`  non-equi (`<=`, `>=`) columns, and assign (`:=`) the corresponding 'val' and 'time' that matches to new columns in the 'df_time'

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df_time)[df_val, c("val", "time")  := .(val, time) , 
         on = .(start <= time,  end >= time)])
#.  start end event_id val time
#1:     5   7        b  20    6
#2:     7  11        c  50   11
#3:     4   7        d  20    6
```

Comment: I do not understand what the above code is doing; can you break it down please? Thank you!

Comment: @CorerMaximus. Added some explanations. Hope it helps

Comment: My apologies on not trying it robustly enough when you posted it. I tried it on some more data values- it does not filter values; instead- opting to perform a left join wherein it keeps all the values from df_time even if there is no matching data. To test- try ```time=c(3,6,10,11)
val=c(100,20,40,50)
df_val=data.frame(time,val)
``` I am removing rows with is.na values in the joined columns after the fact, but is there any way to do it when joining itself?

Comment: @CorerMaximus. I had some difficulty because of the values were not matching in your expected.  Can you update your post with the exact expected

Comment: Updated! My apologies once again on the trouble; instead of removing rows from both dataframes with non-matching values, the solution instead keeps rows from df_time regardless of whether they have a matching df_val counterpart.